# Why is my entire view hierarchy being laid out repeatedly when TalkBack is on?

Tags: android, talkback

I have a fragment which consists of a `RecyclerView` and nothing else.  Normally it works fine, however when I switch on TalkBack a memory leak causes the app to crash.  I have traced the issue back to the fact that the `RecyclerView` is being repeatedly laid out (many times per second) - in fact, according to the stack trace on the `RecyclerView`'s `layout()` method, it is the entire view hierarchy which is being laid out.  What could be causing this to happen only when TalkBack is switched on, and only on one screen of my app?  I have other fragments which use exactly the same layout xml and there are no such issues.

The stack trace I used to try and diagnose the cause indicates that the `ViewRootImpl` `performLayout` method is being called, which is why I state that it is my entire view hierarchy.  What can cause the `ViewRoot` to re-layout?

Comment: That sounds weird. Not knowing anything about TalkBack, I have no idea where I would start. You *should* try to make a minimal example of this (and post that minimal code), though - so that others can check it out, increasing your chances of getting a good answer. ;)

Comment: @SnildDolkow Thanks - I suspect this will be a difficult one to produce a minimal example of but I will see what I can do!